# IsReadonly variable which propagate on many controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `UserControl` window with controls on it.
I would like to add `Enabled` property for this `UserControl` which controls states of `IsReadOnly` property of selected controls.

How can I do it?
Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for each child control in `UserControl` bind `IsReadOnly` property to parent:

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding Enabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type typeOfUserControl}}}">
```

and define `Enabled` [Dependancy property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) for you `UserControl`.

you should also use bool inverse converter to convert enable-to-readonly logic:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
    public class InverseBooleanConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(bool))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

            return !(bool)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

**UPD**:
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx)

> You can use the as operator to perform certain types of conversions
>   between compatible reference types or nullable types.

So:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EnabledDependencyProperty = 
     DependencyProperty.Register( "Enabled", typeof(bool),
     typeof(UserControlType), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));

public bool Enabled
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(EnabledDependencyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(EnabledDependencyProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: How do I define `Enabled` for my `UserControl` here? Tried `get { return base.GetValue(EnabledProperty) as bool; }` but get error (bool is not nullable).

Comment: @JacekWojcik: see UPD.